# How to lambdify a SymPy expression containing the erf function for use with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I would like to lambdify a symbolic expression containing the erf function with SymPy. This can be done for scalar arguments as follows:

```
log_normal = 0.5 + 0.5 * sym.erf((sym.log(x) - mu) / sym.sqrt(2 * sigma**2))
F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal)
F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

I would like to vectorize the above. Normally I would do as follows...

```
log_normal = 0.5 + 0.5 * sym.erf((sym.log(x) - mu) / sym.sqrt(2 * sigma**2))
vector_F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal, modules='numpy')
vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

However the above raises a `NameError`...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-14adde48d4a1> in <module>()
----> 1 vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)

/Users/drpugh/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <lambda>(x, mu,     sigma)

NameError: global name 'erf' is not defined
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You told `lambdify` it only had `numpy` as a module to play with; give it a source for `erf`.  IOW, you have

```
>>> vector_F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal, modules=['numpy'])
>>> vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-10-14adde48d4a1>", line 1, in <module>
    vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'erf' is not defined
```

but

```
>>> vector_F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
>>> vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
0.500000000000000
```

or

```
>>> vector_F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal, modules=['numpy', 'math'])
>>> vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
0.5
```

or whichever `erf` you prefer, depending on whether you want a `sympy.core.numbers.Float` or a `float`.

Comment: You can also use `modules=['numpy', {'erf': scipy.special.erf}]` to use the scipy `erf`.

Comment: @asmeurer I think, this comment should be a separate answer. Using `erf` does not work for me. Using your solution, however, does.

Answer (score 3):

As of SymPy 1.3, scipy is automatically supported in lambdify. If you omit the `modules` argument, it adds scipy automatically. Or you can use `modules=['numpy', 'scipy']`.

```py
>>> log_normal = 0.5 + 0.5 * sym.erf((sym.log(x) - mu) / sym.sqrt(2 * sigma**2))
>>> vector_F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal)
>>> vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
0.5
```

In general, to support a function that lambdify doesn't know about, add it as a dictionary to the `modules` argument. The `modules` argument determines the namespace that the lambdified function is run against. See the [lambdify documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify). For instance, to support erf in SymPy < 1.3:

```py
>>> import scipy.special
>>> vector_F = sym.lambdify([x, mu, sigma], log_normal, modules=['numpy', {'erf': scipy.special.erf}])
>>> vector_F(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
0.5
```