# Lambdify Sympy expression to NumPy containing Mod function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127414/how-to-lambdify-a-sympy-expression-containing-the-erf-function-for-use-with-nump) question I got a problem with lambdifying a sympy expression containing the modulo function.

Minimal example:

```
from sympy import *

modules = [str('numpy'),str('sympy')]

x,y = symbols('x y')
f = x%y
g = lambdify((x,y),f,modules = modules)
g(3.2,3)
```

gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimalexample.py", line 9, in <module>
    g(3.2,3)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'Mod' is not defined
```

Is there a way to make this work?
Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

As answered in the comments I had an old version of sympy installed without noticing

Comment: Works for me in SymPy 1.1.1. Is your SymPy old? The current version is 1.2

Comment: This was actually the problem..the machine I'm working on had an old version of sympy installed and I did not check that -.- Thanks!

Comment: It is also generally not a good idea to mix the sympy and numpy modules. If your expression doesn't have a equivalent function in numpy, the sympy function will be retained. The output of the final function call will then be a sympy expression.